# how to properly submit a spark job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some scala / spark code, packaged into sparktest_2.10-1.0.jar file
I'm trying to do spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --class sparktest_2.10-1.0 --master local[2]
```

I get:  `Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file)`

What is the proper way to do spark-submit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spark-submit
  --class "main-class"
  --master spark://master-url
  --deploy-mode "deploy-mode"
  --conf <key>=<value>  
  ... # other options
  application-jar
  [application-arguments]
```

Eg:

```
spark-submit --class "com.example.myapp" myapp.jar
```

Comment: so, where with this syntax do I actually put my sparktest_2.10-1.0.jar ?

Comment: You have to mention the entire jar name. And the complete classpath